# AMPL how to have a summation constraint

Tags: sum, constraints, indices, ampl

I need a constraint that sums according to the following indices:

```
subject to shift[1]: x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[1,4] + x[1,5] + x[1,6] >= 8;
subject to shift[2]: x[1,2] + x[2,3] + x[2,4] + x[2,5] + x[2,6] >= 7;
subject to shift[3]: x[1,3] + x[2,3] + x[3,4] + x[3,5] + x[3,6] >= 12;
subject to shift[4]: x[1,4] + x[2,4] + x[3,4] + x[4,5] + x[4,6] >= 9;
subject to shift[5]: x[1,5] + x[2,5] + x[3,5] + x[4,5] + x[5,6] >= 6;
subject to shift[6]: x[1,6] + x[2,6] + x[3,6] + x[4,6] + x[5,6] >= 10;
```

What I have is:

```
param n;                        # number of shifts possible
param demand {i in 1..n};       # demand of workers at each shift
var x {1..n, 1..n} >= 0;        # number of workers per shift
# minimize function
subject to shift {t in 1..n}: sum{j in 1..(n)} x[t,j] >= demand[t];
```

This is wrong as it gives the following:

```
subject to shift[1]: x[1,1] + x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[1,4] + x[1,5] + x[1,6] >= 8;
subject to shift[2]: x[2,1] + x[2,2] + x[2,3] + x[2,4] + x[2,5] + x[2,6] >= 7;
subject to shift[3]: x[3,1] + x[3,2] + x[3,3] + x[3,4] + x[3,5] + x[3,6] >= 12;
subject to shift[4]: x[4,1] + x[4,2] + x[4,3] + x[4,4] + x[4,5] + x[4,6] >= 9;
subject to shift[5]: x[5,1] + x[5,2] + x[5,3] + x[5,4] + x[5,5] + x[5,6] >= 6;
subject to shift[6]: x[6,1] + x[6,2] + x[6,3] + x[6,4] + x[6,5] + x[6,6] >= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
param n;                        # number of shifts possible
param demand {i in 1..n};       # demand of workers at each shift
var x {i in 1..n-1, j in 1..n} >= 0;        # number of workers per shift
#minimize function
subject to shift {t in 1..n}: sum {i in 1..n-1, j in i+1..n} (if i=t || j=t then 1 else 0)*x[i,j] >= demand[t];
```

Comment: If you're happy with this solution, you can mark it as "accepted", so other readers can see that it's resolved and doesn't need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You've already posted a good solution, but for the sake of variety, here are a couple of other ways to achieve the same result:

```
s.t. shift{t in 1..n}: sum{i in 1..n-1, j in i+1..n: i=t || j=t} x[i,j] >= demand[t]; 

s.t. shift{t in 1..n}: sum{i in 1..t-1, j=t} x[i,j] + sum{i = t, j in t+1..n} x[i,j] >= demand[t];
```

The second is less elegant, but if n is very large it might be more efficient since it avoids creating all the cases where neither i nor j equals t.